# angularjs doesn't return string value, but other types

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript and Angularjs to get data from the server, but when I try to display the data on the page, only the string type doesn't show up while the rest shows up as expected. The data is parsed to json which I can see the data that I want. I'm not sure if it's angularjs or typescript although I think it's typescript. I might have missed something.

It is the `Name` property that doesn't display while the `Count` shows up as expected

```
 var promise = $http.get("/data/book").success(
                function (data) {
                    var response = data;
                    $scope.Book= [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        var Name = response[i].Name;
                        var Count = response[i].Count;

                        $scope.Book.push(new Book(Name, Count));
                    }
```

Comment: What does your `data` look like? Post some JSON if you can. Also, I presume you're unrolling that `Book` array with `ng-repeat`. Post that code too.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to deserialize the message, as you'll have a JSON string, not a JavaScript object:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);
```

If you are sure that Angular has already done this for you as per the comment from @aapierce, you should check the structure of the object. For example, the following line could be suspect:

```
var response = data;
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
```

For example, is the array the parent of the response? Perhaps you are after (for example) `response.books.length` rather than `response.length`. Obviously, this entirely depends on the JSON, so if you post that the answer can be far more definitive.

Comment: Not entirely true. Based on the [tutorial on Angular's site](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05), the `data` object can be a JSON object instead of a string. Since it's certainly possible to request *any* type of data (not just JSON), I presume Angular is smart enough to look at the `content-type` header of the HTTP response and parse it appropriately (however, in 10 minutes of searching I wasn't able to find any definitive source to confirm or deny this).

Comment: I got it display the information needed. It was just a small mistake I made in my code. I don't need to deserialize the message because the data I receive from the server is JSON string.

Comment: @Lynn If you don't mind, please post the "small mistake" that you made in an answer. Someone else might find this question later on, wondering how you solved your problem!

Comment: @aapierce you are right - the Angular JS docs says it will deserialize JSON `if a JSON response is detected`.